# How to group in sql and show min and max time without showing distinct result on the grouped field

Tags: sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I am trying view the differences in a specific fields overtime, and for that I am requesting the minimum and maximum time that the specific field has been shown in the table. The problem is that it shows me the absolute minimum and maximum time of the field being shown but I wish to see only the minimum and maximum time of each consecutive show.

For example, lets say my table looks like:

```
Time                | Name

2020-04-17 06:00:15 | John
2020-04-18 12:00:15 | John
2020-04-19 06:00:15 | Jackson
2020-04-19 08:00:15 | Jackson
2020-04-19 16:00:15 | Jackson
2020-04-19 20:00:15 | John
2020-04-20 06:00:15 | John
2020-04-21 06:00:15 | Jackson
2020-04-22 06:00:15 | Jackson
```

My desired results are:

```
Min(Time)           Max(Time)           Name

2020-04-17 06:00:15 2020-04-18 12:00:15 John
2020-04-19 06:00:15 2020-04-16 06:00:15 Jackson
2020-04-19 20:00:15 2020-04-20 06:00:15 John
2020-04-21 06:00:15 2020-04-22 06:00:15 Jackson
```

But the results I am getting with my SQL Query are:

```
SELECT MIN(Time), MAX(Time), Name
from table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY MAX(Time) DESC
```

```
Min(Time)           Max(Time)           Name

2020-04-17 06:00:15 2020-04-20 06:00:15 John
2020-04-19 06:00:15 2020-04-22 06:00:15 Jackson
```

which shows, absolute min and max time :(

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Which engine are you using? SQL Server, OracleSQL, PostgreSQL,...?

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  For this, use the difference of row numbers:

```
select name, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by time) as seqnum_n
      from t
     ) t
group by name, (seqnum - seqnum_n);
```

How this works is a little hard to explain.  If you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the adjacent rows that you want are defined by the difference in row number.

Answer (score 0):

Add another column, say "show_id" and then query by

```
SELECT MIN(Time), MAX(Time), Name, show_id
from table
GROUP BY Name, show_id
ORDER BY MAX(Time) DESC
```